# How can I automate a SQL query via PHPMyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, automation, phpmyadmin

Because of a buggy wordpress plugin I am using, I have to manually run the following query many times during a single day:

```
update table_name set column_name="";
```

It simply drops the contents of the given column name. 
So how can I make my server do it automatically every 30 minutes for instance, through PHPMyadmin?

I am not a PHP nor a SQL SAVVY. So please take that into consideration :)
I am on Hostmonster.com , and they have MySQL client version: 5.1.60 and phpMyAdmin v. 3.4.9

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, PHPMyAdmin can not automate it directly.

You have a few options:

- Create a cron job to run the SQL statement (too advanced?)
- Utilize [WP Cron](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) to schedule an event to run the SQL statement through WordPress. (possibly easier)
- Fix the plugin (my vote, but could be difficult)

Comment: Hi Jason. Thank you. I have no idea what a cron job is. If it is the same thing Karlson proposed below, I dont really know whether it is a Windows or a Unix server. I have indeed paid someone $150 to fix the plugin :)
Your second suggestions seems to need PHP knowledge, which I sadly dont have. Will consider the other answers, thanx !

Comment: A cron job is what **Karlson** provided code for. Now worries. Glad you got it solved. If you need WordPress development in the future, feel free to [reach out to me](http://jason.pureconcepts.net).

Comment: Yes I will still something to be changed later after the developer finishes, will contact u. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

If are using UNIX and like you can put the following into your crontab:

```
30 * * * * "/<path_to_mysql>/mysql -u <username> -p<password> -e "update table set column=\"\""
```

This will do every 30 minutes what you need to do.

For Windows you can create a Batch file that does the same and execute it using [Windows Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

Comment: Thanx Karlson. Please see my reponse to Jason above.

Comment: @Mouad Placement notwithstanding but $150 seems a bit excessive.  Glad it's resolved tho.

Comment: @Karlson Well it is actually not resolved yet.. the developer is just stretching it.. I am using a shared hosting at Hostmonster.com .. I it is a Linux, so how can I run this "cronjob"?  What is the path to mysql?

Comment: @Mouad if you have a shell login you can simply do: `crontab -e` and as far as `mysql` is concerned you can do `which mysql` from the shell but standard locations are `/usr/bin/mysql` and `/usr/local/bin/mysql`

Answer (score 1):

While it is a bit of work to do this **every N minutes**, it is quite easy to do it **statistically every N requests**. Put

```
<?php
define('MYPLUGIN_CLEANUP_PROBABILITY',5);

function myplugin_cleanup_db($postid) {
  global $wpdb;
  if (rand(0,99)<MYPLUGIN_CLEANUP_PROBABILITY))
    $wpdb->query('update table_name set column_name=""');
}

add_action('shutdown', 'myplugin_cleanup_db');
?>
```

into a .php file and put it into your plugins directory after adapting your cleanup probability. Then activate this plugin and off you go.

Comment: Thank you Eugen. Could you please tell me is "adapting cleanup probability"? Where can I set the time intervals (30 minutes) that I want the plugin to be executed at?